# SQLAlchemy - Latest of many to many relationship

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, pydantic

I'm currently building an API (using SQLAlchemy, FastAPI and Pydantic) that stores information about apartments and it's residents. An apartment can only be taken by one resident at a time, but we store the history. The data model is as follows:

```py
class Resident(Base):
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(200))


class Apartment(Base):
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, nullable=False)
    address = Column(String(200))

    residents = relationship("Occupation")


class Occupation(Base):
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, nullable=False)

    start = Column(Date)
    end = Column(Date)

    resident_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("residents.id"))
    resident = relationship("Resident")

    apartment_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("apartments.id"))
    apartment = relationship("Apartment")
```

The 'residents' relation on apartment will give me a 1-N relation to occupation. But what I would like to have, is a relation that gives me the current resident for a given apartment in a 1-1 way.

The following query is used to get all apartments and owners:

```py
db.query(models.Apartment).options(
    joinedload(models.Apartment.residents).joinedload(models.Occupation.resident),
).all()
```

Using a Pydantic schema, this translates into the following JSON:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "4c260b11-0b93-4e68-a931-5facfb6bac52",
        "address": "X",
        "residents": [
            {
                "start": "2021-01-01",
                "end": "2021-12-31",
                "resident": {
                    "id": "982f6398-5213-4b07-8187-2d5606ee4142",
                    "name": "Steve Jobs"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But what I'm looking for, is:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "4c260b11-0b93-4e68-a931-5facfb6bac52",
        "address": "X",
        "current_resident": {
            "id": "982f6398-5213-4b07-8187-2d5606ee4142",
            "name": "Steve Jobs"
        }
    }
]
```

Is there a SQLAlchemy way to achieve this?

Comment: You could store the ID of the current resident in the Apartment object and just use the association object (Occupation) for history. That way you can get the current resident immediately and you can also easily determine which apartments are vacant (current_resident IS NULL) and which ones are occupied (current_resident IS NOT NULL).

Comment: That is correct, but this will need to be updated on the date a resident leaves. So this will require some ETL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is add an additional `viewonly` relationship to the `Apartment` where you filter on the current date:

```py
today = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
current_resident = relationship("Resident",
        secondary="occupation",
        primaryjoin=f'and_(Occupation.apartment_id == Apartment.id, \
                           Occupation.start <= "{today}", \
                           Occupation.end > "{today}")',
        secondaryjoin="Occupation.resident_id == Resident.id",
        uselist=False,
        viewonly=True
        )
```

This returns the `Resident` object of the current resident or `None` when there is no resident on the current date.